# Predicate to find intersection of array of integer property with collection?

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate, realm-list

I have an object that has a `List<Int>` property:

```
class Products: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  dynamic var price: Double = 0
  dynamic var categories = List<Int>()
}
```

From the user, I get an array of categories ID's that I need to grab all products in `Realm` that have at least one category in the list.

I tried a few things but nothing worked:

```
realm.objects(Products.self).filter("ANY categories IN %@", ids)
realm.objects(Products.self).filter("SUBQUERY(categories, $id, $id IN %@).@count > 0", ids)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with `Realm` filter predicate?

Comment: You can check against a property of `categories.id` if `categories = List<Category>`, but you cannot check against elements in a `List<Int>`. If you need this feature, nag Realm at https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513